# Send e-mail with attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have implemented simple e-mail service which I want to extend with file attachment. This is the code so far:

```
private String sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body)
    {
        String status;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try
        {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
            {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++)
            {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        }
        catch (AddressException ae)
        {
            ae.printStackTrace();
            return status = "Cannot send Message!";
        }
        catch (MessagingException me)
        {
            me.printStackTrace();
            return status = "Cannot send Message!";
        }

        return status = "Message is send!";
    }
```

As attachment I would like to use this object:

```
private Part file;
```

I tried to implement it this way using [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm) code:

```
private Part file;
........

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
//            String file = "path of file to be attached";
//            String fileName = "attachmentName";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource((File) file);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);
```

I get this error:

```
serverError: class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart cannot be cast to java.io.File
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: An `ApplicationPart` isn't a `File`.  You can't just cast objects to arbitrary types.

Comment: @azurefrog can you propose some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`//     String file = "...";
DataSource source = new FileDataSource((File) file);`

with:

`String pathToFile = "...";
 DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(pathTofile));`

Comment: I get no suitable constructor found for File(Part)
    constructor File.File(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Part cannot be converted to String)
    constructor File.File(URI) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Part cannot be converted to URI)

Comment: Oh, I did not see the upper declaration of "file". I edited my answer.

Comment: Update: I'm using JSF 2.2 to upload the file into object. See this example: https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/jsf22-file-upload/ S owhe nI upload the file it's stored as `private Part file;` The issue is how I can send the file object?

Comment: Try to get `part.getInputStream()` and add this as attachment.

Comment: Use part.getInputStream() with [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html#ByteArrayDataSource(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)), instead of using FileDataSource.